# How must a OData 3.0 response look like, that WCF detects an error

Tags: c#, wcf, odata

I am implementing a .net OData client with WCF. This uses OData version 3. The service is implemented by a vendor. When saving an object with a missing property, the server returns an error. But the error response does not have the right format ([Specification](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/atom-format/)). Therefore, the `DataServiceContext.SaveChanges(...)` method always throws:

> System.Net WebException: "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."

With this exception I don't have any possibility to get the reason of the error--no InnerException is set.

How does such an error response look like, so that the WCF DataServiceContext.SaveChanges(...) detects an error and I can get the information I need?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I used [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to change the response from the server. With this I tried to find the right formatted response. This is the last version I tried after rereading the specification and considering the comments:

```
HTTP/1.1 40 Bad Request
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/atom+xml;type=feed
Date: Wed, 11 May 2016 08:02:07 GMT
Content-Length: 243
DataServiceVersion: 3.0;

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
  <m:code />
  <m:message xml:lang="en-US">
    Resource not found for the segment 'Productss'.
  </m:message>
</m:error>
```

Sadly it's still not working.

Comment: Are you sure both the client and the server are using OData version 3?

Comment: I'm sure about the client. The server is from a vendor and said to be OData version 3.0 but seams to be implemented by hand.

Comment: Look for a `DataServiceVersion` header in the response from the service. Read up on versioning in the [OData v3 spec](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/odata-version-3-0-core-protocol/).

Comment: Thanks for your response, but by now this doesn't work. I will edit the question, to show what I get as response by now.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is not because the client cannot read the response, it's an `Exception` that's telling you that the server didn't "like" the request you sent to it.

**400 Bad Request** is usually used to notify a client that the request it sent to server was malformed.

The error should go away once you send the request to server in the correct structure.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I'm sure that I send the request in the right structure, because the service (which is under my controll) recieves the request and processes the request. During processing, an error occurs, cause e.g. a newly added object has some property values missing. Now, the server should response with an error, that is OData compliant. How does this response must look like, that the WCF client recognises it as an OData error and does not throw the `WebException`. The `400 Bad Request` is what actually is returned by the server.

Comment: Look at [this](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/odata-version-3-0-core-protocol/), section 9.2, it seems that this is the response you should be getting. I don't think the client has the capability of throwing an `OData` specific `Exception`, as `OData` uses `HTTP` response codes, so a `WebException` fits the result the server returned.

Comment: But with the `WebException` I loose access to the response of the server. I just get the Statuscode and cannot determine, why the error occurs, even if it is in the response traced with [wireshark](http://wireshark.org).

Comment: The `Exception`'s message doesn't have the content of the error that was returned from the server?

Comment: No, that's the bad thing.

Comment: Did you try [WCF Data Services Client Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668772(v=vs.110).aspx)?
It might expose the server error through a `DataServiceQueryException` instead of a `WebException`.

Comment: I use the [`DataServiceContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext(v=vs.113).aspx) which is part of the client library and call its `SaveChanges(...)`` method. I also assumed to get a `DataServiceQueryException` - but did not. This is the source of my question.

Comment: `SaveChanges` should return a `DataServiceResponse`, you might be able to get the error information through there.
You can read more about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.savechanges(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: `SaveChanges` returns the response just in the case, no exception is thrown. But that happens in my case.

Comment: Then maybe `SaveChanges` is trying to send too much to the server at once and it exceeds the max request size.